# Change selected item color in material ui list button event

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have sidebar with buttons, when i click on one i want to set color on selected button but it doesn't work properly because sometimes it requires clicking twice to set the color i don't know why. When i set setSelectedIndex(1) but in console.log(selectedIndex) shows  0

```
import { Drawer, List, ListItem, ListItemButton, ListItemText, styled, Toolbar } from '@mui/material'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { sideItems } from './SideItems';

const Sidebar: React.FC = () => {

    const drawerWidth = 240;
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);

    const StyledListText = styled(ListItemText)({
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'white'
    });

    const CustomListButton = styled(ListItemButton)({
        "&.Mui-selected": {
            backgroundColor: "#2e8b57!important"
        }
    });


    const handleListItemClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>, path: string, index: number) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        navigate(path);
        setSelectedIndex(index);
    }

    return (
        <Drawer
            variant="permanent"
            sx={{
                width: drawerWidth,
                [`& .MuiDrawer-paper`]: { width: drawerWidth, boxSizing: 'border-box' }
            }}
            PaperProps={{
                elevation: 12,
                sx: {
                    width: 240,
                    backgroundColor: "primary.light"
                }
            }}
        >
            <Toolbar />
            <List>
                {sideItems.map((item, index) =>
                    <ListItem key={item.id}>
                        <CustomListButton selected={index === selectedIndex} onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, item.path, index)}>
                            <StyledListText primary={item.text} />
                        </CustomListButton>
                    </ListItem>
                )}
            </List>

        </Drawer>
    )
}

export default Sidebar
```

Comment: `navigate()` in `handleListItemClick` is causing the issue, because each time you select the item the page gets navigated to a path and the `selectedIndex` will be `reset to 0`. Try to `derive the selectedIndex` from the `path / url`.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely here you are including `<Sidebar/>` as child component inside the jsx of every page component so each time you are creating a new instance of it and since the initial `selectedIndex` value is 0 it is always the first item which is selected no matter to which page component you have been redirected with `navigate`, unless you click on another button to update `selectedIndex` value of this new `Sidebar` instance.

What you should do it to use `<Sidebar/>` on the top level to create only one instance of it, so it does not lose it's `hooks` values something like this :

```
function Layout(props) {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Siderbar/>
      <main>{props.children}</main>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can write your question better:**

1. Don't need write in this example:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { sideItems } from './SideItems';
```

2. You must in example write const *sideItems*

```
const sideItems = [
  {
    id: '1',
    text: 'lalala',
    path: 'lololo'
  }
]
```

**Solutions:**

1. You can write solution - boolean:

(change your strings)

```
const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(true);
const handleListItemClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>, path: string, index: number) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setSelectedIndex(!selectedIndex);
}
<CustomListButton selected={selectedIndex} onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, item.path, index)}>
```

2. You can write solution - number:

(change your strings)

```
const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);
const handleListItemClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>, path: string, index: number) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setSelectedIndex((prev) => {
    return prev ? 0 : 1
  });
}
<CustomListButton selected={!!selectedIndex} onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, item.path, index)}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank, you guys for help I found solution for my case
I added

```js
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and rest looks like

```js
{sideItems.map((item) =>
    <ListItemButton sx={{
        "&.Mui-selected": {
            backgroundColor: "#2e8b57!important"
        }
    }} key={item.id} component={Link} to={item.path} selected={location.pathname === item.path}>
        <StyledListText primary={item.text} />
    </ListItemButton>
)}
```